# Jquery scroll to div on new page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

Im trying to implement a jQuery plugin to automatically scroll down to a page on a new screen,
example:

www.mysite.com (page loads on header)

www.mysite.com/#div1 (page loads on div1)

Here is my jQuery code

```
<script>
    if(window.location.hash) {
        var hash = window.location.hash; //Puts hash in variable
        // hash found
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Handler for .ready() called.
        $('html, body').animate({ 
            scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
        }, 2000); 
        alert();
    });
</script>
```

At the moment, when I open a menu item on a new screen, it does not scroll down. I get this error on Chrome console:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Comment: So what is the problem you are facing with the code ? Please add complete details about what exactly you are looking for.

Comment: @Rndm when i right click the menu and choose open in a new window, the page does not scroll down to the selected div

Comment: Well you are going to have an issue when hash is not defined and the browser should already be scrolled to the position when the page loads in the first place.

Comment: @epascarello i got this error on browser console:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if (location.hash) {
          $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(location.hash).offset().top
          }, 2000); 
        }       
    });
</script>
```

If you are interested, you can check [jquery.localScroll](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.localScroll) which simplifies this and also making all links on the page scroll automatically. You need to set the `hash` setting to true for that.

Comment: just control+c control+v your code and it did not work. should i add something else?

Comment: This should do nothing unless the url has a correct hash of course, click an anchor link, then refresh and it should scroll

Comment: Worked, thanks :) the problem I had was this: my theme had a JS to lock the scroll until page fully load. I add your code to it, and it worked, thanks for the help